# Add elements of a list to the same list in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Is it possible to the following? If yes, does it have any drawbacks or is there a better way to do this?

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(2);
myList.add(3);

// then add all the elements again
myList.add(myList);
```

Comment: Did you try? Trying is the best way to test if something is possible or not.

Comment: Actually you can do in a traditional way with using a `for` loop

Answer (score 4):

The `addAll` method of `ArrayList` happens to work in Oracle's JDK (and OpenJDK). But it is not guaranteed to. The [Javadoc for `addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) says:

> The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this list, and this list is nonempty.)

The question is actually not as pointless as some of the answers imply. Just "trying it" is not a sufficient test that something works correctly, as this case proves.

In fact, when thinking about whether `list.addAll(list)` works, you need to ask yourself how it might be implemented. If it was simply iterating over `list` and adding each element to the end of `list`, you'd get a `ConcurrentModificationException` (or else it would go into an infinite loop). That's why the Javadoc doesn't guarantee that such a call works. As it happens, Oracle's implementation copies the passed list to an array first, and then copies each element of the array to the end of the list. This means that calling `addAll` for a list might not be as efficient as doing it yourself without creating an extra copy.

Comment: Thanks  for the explanation, what would you recommend?

Comment: @daljit97 either of the two other answers showing ways of doing this safely. Andy Turner shows `myList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(myList));`. This has the advantage of being succinct, but it creates a copy of `myList` even though Oracle's implementation also creates another copy. This would be my preferred way as it's more readable, but if the list is very long and you don't have enough memory to make the extra copy, use Khaled K's way involving the use of a loop calling `get(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

In case of basic data types (Boolean, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String) they are immutable, meaning they will always be passed-by-value.

```
Integer X = 10;
Integer Y = X; // Y is 10, X is 10
Y = 20;        // Y is 20, X is 10
X = 30;        // Y is 20, X is 30

String A = "Test";
String B = A; // B is a copy of A; A & B are distinct
```

But the problem arise when you store objects, if you try to assign, you will end up copying the reference not the value.

```
Object C = new Object();
Object D = C; // C & D points at the same object
```

The best practice is to copy, otherwise if you work with Objects, you will end up with multiple references to the same objects.

```
class MyObj { private int val; public MyObj(int v){ val=v; } ..}

ArrayList<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
list.add(new MyObj(2));
list.add(new MyObj(3));

list.addAll(list);
```

You might think the list has 4 objects now, except you'd be wrong, it has 2 references to 2 different objects each, a simple test will show how.

```
// prints: 2 3 2 3
for(MyObj m : list) System.out.print(" "+m.getVal());

// modify first item to 5
list.get(0).setVal(5);

// prints: 5 3 5 3
for(MyObj m : list) System.out.print(" "+m.getVal());
```

You can clone objects by either creating and initiating the objects manually.

```
int oldSize = list.size();
for(int i=0; i<oldSize; i++)
{
    MyObj m = list.get(i);
    MyObj t = new MyObj();
    t.setVal(m.getVal());
    list.add(t); // append
}
```

You can also have a copy-constructor and pass the object you want to clone onto.

```
class MyObj
{
    ..
    public MyObj(MyObj o)
    {
        val = o.getVal();
    }
}

int oldSize = list.size();
for(int i=0; i<oldSize; i++)
{
    MyObj m = list.get(i);
    list.add(new MyObj(m)); // append
}
```

Moreover your objects class can implement the interface `Cloneable` and extend the `clone` method.

```
class MyObj implements Cloneable
{
    ..
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {  
        return (MyObj)super.clone();
    }
}

int oldSize = list.size();
for(int i=0; i<oldSize; i++)
{
    MyObj m = list.get(i);
    list.add(m.clone()); // append
}
```

Comment: `for(MyObj m : list) list.add(whatever);` will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are adding to the list while iterating it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thx for the note, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The main drawback with `myList.add(myList);` is that it won't compile, because `myList` isn't an `Integer`.

You can, however, use:

```
myList.addAll(myList);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Dtm3hF)

or

```
myList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(myList));
```

if you want to do it safely.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList.addAll(myList);
```

=> Works.

```
myList.add(myList);
```

=> Won't compile, .add method requires an Integer (not int) as argument, you cannot call using another List.

Comment: It "works" in Oracle's implementation but is not guaranteed to work by the API specification (see my answer for details)

Comment: `ArrayList<Collection<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(list);` This works.